# Does Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) support Arabic?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Is there any support for Arabic in Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)?
or recent release for Arabic?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this time we do not have any models for Arabic !!